# How to write a console application using Py3k?

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

I found that many books and tutorial now is teaching how to write GUI application, but I would like to write an old school console application. But I don't know how to start. For example, I don't know how to write a frame in console application, how to listen the event in a console application.

Is that all the UI is using the `print()` to "draw" the UI? or there is a tool to do so? Also, how to move the cursor position? Last but not least, how to listen the key user inputted? Thanks.

Comment: A Console app is usually using only stdin/stdout. What you are talking about are more specifically TUI's. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface Calling it "console" is perhaps not wrong, but unspecific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used it myself but [curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) should be a good starting point.

It is the "de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling"